# Чим відрізняються між собою лексеми "зварник", "зварювач" та "зварювальник"?

Tags: терміни

В [Антисуржику](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244) знайшла лише варіант **"зварювальник"**.

У [Словнику української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=34669&page=1104) - усі три варіанти.

Цікавить, чи можна використовувати усі три терміни на позначення тієї самої професії? Чи є між цими словами "відтінок"?  Якщо так, то чим вони між собою відрізняються?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тлумачний словник української мови віддає перевагу більш частотній на час складання статей назві *зварник*. *Зварювальник* і *зварювач* подає як рідковживані. У значеннях вони тотожні - "фахівець, що займається зварюванням."
 Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський) надає цікавий варіант:

> Спогріва́льник, -ка – сварщик.

Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський) вказує лише один відповідник:

> Сварщик – зва́рювач (-ча).

Варіативність суфіксів -ник і -ч на позначення професій дуже докладно висвітлено в [статті Стаховської Н. Ф.](http://www.confcontact.com/2013-specproekt/fl8_stahovska.htm). Якщо спиратися на це дослідження, то зварник не відповідає принципам утворення українських назв професій.

Comment: «Словник української мови» 2010-х років уже не подає біля «зварювальник» слова помітки «рідко». Отже вважаймо, що «зварник»=«зварювальник» (хоч у [переліку професій](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_професій) лише «зварник»). Щодо «зварювач», то він має ще одне значення (причому без помітки «рідко») — «пристрій для зварювання».